# How to add peers dynamically to an existing hyperledger fabric network using node sdk?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain

In all of the tutorials , I see that we can add an organization or peer manually to  an existing fabric network. But how do i dynamically assign an incoming node as a peer or an orderer depending on some criteria?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about adding peer to fabric network using node sdk, but you can definitely add peer by using CLI.

For that you need to generate crypto material for new Peer and joining the existing channel

Please follow below link for more detail

[Extending Hyperledger Fabric Network: Adding a New Peer](https://medium.com/@wahabjawed/extending-hyperledger-fabric-network-adding-a-new-peer-4f52f70a7217)